# How to keep IE session alive more than 5 mins?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a page where its taking time to render data i want to keep IE session alive. I tried below but its giving me error `Unexpected quantifier`.

How to resolve this issue ?

main.html

```
<img id="keepAliveIMG" width="0" height="0" src="images/glyph_error.png" />
```

ctrl.js

```
   function keepMeAlive(imgName) {
      myImg = document.getElementById(imgName);
      if (myImg) myImg.src = myImg.src.replace(/?.*$/, '?' + Math.random());
   }
   window.setInterval("keepMeAlive('keepAliveIMG')", 100000);
```